# javascript popunder, but different pop depending on country

Tags: javascript

I got the following popunder script (it gets called on the pages i want it on)
Which works 100% fine.
But i wanted to ask if it is possible to add a rule that people from germany get popped a different window.

My question above is my entire question, but it won't allow me to post my question. Because aparantly my code block is to large compared to my question size. So here i am filling up the space till it will say i have the correct ratio of code and text. This last block is entirely useless, but hey, i have to write it. I basicly dont know javascript, but found this working code online a while ago, and been using it since. hoping to make it more usefull for my cause with this addition.

```
function doMyStuff($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var ran_yet = false;
    $("a,body,input").click(function() {
      if (ran_yet) {
        return;
      }
      ran_yet = true;
      var cookiename = 'nopop';
      var val = getCookie(cookiename);
      if (!val) {
        val = 1;
      } else {
        val = parseInt(val);
      }
      setCookie(cookiename, val + 1, 1);      
      if (val != 1) {
        return;
      }
window.name = "parent";
      var windowprops = "fullscreen=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes";
      var myWin = window.open("http://www.mypopupurl.com/", "", windowprops);
var goBack = window.open('', 'parent');
goBack.focus();
    });
  });
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays,path)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ("; path=/");
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}


function check() {
return window.jQuery && jQuery.fn && /^1\.[3-9]/.test(jQuery.fn.jquery);
  }

if ( check() ) {

doMyStuff( jQuery );

} else {

var script = document.createElement('script'),

timer = setInterval(function(){
  if ( check() ) {
    clearInterval(timer);
      document.body.removeChild(script);
      doMyStuff( jQuery.noConflict(true) );
      }
    }, 30);

script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js';

document.body.insertBefore( script, document.body.firstChild );

}
```